# What is the space efficiency of a directed acyclic word graph (dawg)? and is there a javascript implementation?

Tags: javascript

I have a dictionary of keywords that I want to make available for autocomplete/suggestion on the client side of a web application.  The ajax turnaround introduces too much latency, so it would nice to store the entire word list on the client.

The list could be hundreds of thousands of words, maybe a couple of million.  I did a little bit of research, and it seams that a dawg structure would provide space and lookup efficiency, but I can't find real world numbers.

Also, feel free to suggest other possibilities for achieving the same functionality.

Comment: On further reflection, after reading Aaron's answer below, the ajax latency is likely not the issue.  The question regarding dawg, or other lexicon storage, efficiency still remains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have recently implemented DAWG for a wordgame playing program. It uses a dictionary consisting of 2,7 million words from Polish language. Source plain text file is about 33MB in size. The same word list represented as DAWG in binary file takes only 5MB. Actual size may vary, as it depends on implementation, so number of vertices - 154k and number of edges - 411k are more important figures.

Still, that amount of data is far too big to handle by JavaScript, as stated above. Trying to process several MB of data will hang JavaScript interpreter for a few minutes, effectively hanging whole browser.

Answer (score 1):

My mind cringes at the two facts "couple of million" and "JavaScript". JS is meant to shuffle little pieces of data around, not megabytes. Just imagine how long users would have to wait for your page to load!

There must be a reason why AJAX turnaround is so slow in your case. Google serves billion of AJAX requests every day and their type ahead is snappy (just try it on www.google.com). So there must be something broken in your setup. Find it and fix it.

Comment: Aaron, that's an excellent point.  Google's suggest turns around in less than <100ms which is certainly fast enough.  I'm still curious about efficiency numbers on dawg structures though.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution sounds practical, but you still might want to look at, for example, jQuery's autocomplete implementation(s) to see how they deal with latency.

Comment: thanks. i'm actually planning on combining some better storage/lookup mechanism with jQuery's autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of million words in memory (in JavaScript in a Browser)? That sounds big regardless of what kind of structure you decide to store it in. Your might consider other kinds of optimizations instead, like loading subsets of your wordlist based on the characters typed.

For example, if the user enters "a" then you'd start retrieving all the words that start with "a". Then you could optimize your wordlist by returning more common words first, so the more likely ones will match up "instantly" while less common words may load a little slower.

Answer (score 0):

from my undestanding, DAWGs are good for storing and searching for words, but not when you need to generate lists of matches. Once you located the prefix, you will have to browser thru all its children to reconstruct the words which start with this prefix.

I agree with others, you should consider server-side search.